# Where to put "-p" for solving "pptpd is not running"?

Tags: 14.04, vpn, bug-reporting, debug, pptpd

I'm working with pptpd on 14.04
and got a problem that when run `/etc/init.d/pptpd start` and
`/etc/init.d/pptpd status`, it states that `/use/sbin/pptpd is not running`.

I'm searching for a reason and found https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pptpd/+bug/1296835

However, I can't understand about `-p`, where to put it in?

Thank you for your helping, I'm stuck in this part for a week :)

Comment: Please subscribe to the bug you noted so that the developers can get an idea of how many people are effective. This may be helpful in getting the bug squashed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit `/etc/init.d/pptpd`, and look for a line like:

```
status_of_proc "$PIDFILE" "$DAEMON" ...
```

And add `-p` before `$PIDFILE`:

```
status_of_proc -p "$PIDFILE" "$DAEMON" ...
```